# PHP Form passing input values to url

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that the user has to input number contract and a code like so:

```
 <form action="index.php?option=com_platiniumchristmas&cartao=<?php echo $_GET['cartao']?>&contrato=contract&codigo=code"  method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user tip" title="Utilizador"></i>
                    </span>
                        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="contract" id="contract" class="input form-control" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="Num. Contrato" required="" value="">
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock tip" title="Senha"></i>
                    </span>
                        <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="codigo" id="code" class="input form-control" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="Codigo" required="" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>  
<input type="hidden" name="cartao" id="cartao"  value="<?php echo $_POST['cartao']?>"/>
<input type="submit"value="Login" id="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right"  />
</form>
```

I have to post those values into an url so that the other page recives this values. But what is happing is instead of putting the id on my form action url it does nothing. Can any one help me with this issue.

The Hidden field is to call a function inside of a the form like so:

```
<?php                                       
            function validateUser($contrato, $codigo)
            {
                $url = 'http://managerexternal.medicare.pt/MedicareManager_External.svc?wsdl';
                $client = new SoapClient($url);
                $paramsMC = array('schema'=>'mctestes','numcContrato'=>$contrato, 'codigo'=>$codigo);
                $paramsGC = array('schema'=>'gctestes','numcContrato'=>$contrato, 'codigo'=>$codigo);

                    if($client->AuthenticatedUserByContratoCodigo($paramsMC) == true){

                        $controller = new getInfoContact();// Instanciar Class              
                        $controller->getuserInfo('mctestes',$contrato);
                        $_GET['schema']="mctestes";             

                        $controllerNumeroCartao = new getInfoContact();// Instanciar Class
                        $_POST['cartao']=$controllerNumeroCartao->getNumCartao('mctestes',$contrato);



            } 
?>
```

I need to a function to get value for "cartao". Then I need to send through an url the contact and code value that where set by the user. With does two values I call a function to get the users "cartao".

Comment: You're using `$_GET` in your form action and `$_POST` in your hidden field. Is the hidden field value being set?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and your "action" is incomplete. Too many syntax errors here and we don't know what your PHP looks like.

Comment: You should get all values in $_GET["contract"] and $_GET["codigo"] and $_GET["cartao"]

Comment: Please make sure to escape user input before putting it in your HTML. This code is wide open to XSS attacks. Use `htmlspecialchars($_GET['contract'])` etc.

Comment: turn error reporting ON and view your HTML source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is wrong

```
 <form action="index.php?option=com_platiniumchristmas&cartao=<?php echo $_GET['cartao']?>&contrato=contract&codigo=codigo  method="get">
```

should be

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_platiniumchristmas&cartao=<?php echo $_GET['cartao'];?>&contrato=contract&codigo=codigo"  method="get">
```

Comment: I fixed it. I copied wrong my code. Sorry. I all ready fix it.